# how can i remove the angle's box of dropdown?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

how to disable this angle ?

[image]

i am using boostrap where i get it from [getboostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download)

this is my code..

```
<div class="navbar" >
              <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="dropdown-tonggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SubMenu </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a>sub_1</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a>nomor 2</a></li>
                            <li><a>nomor 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li >
                        <a>MID</a>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                   <ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-inverse pull-right">
                    <li>
                        <a>Right</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>asdfb</a>
                    </li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
</div>
```

i tried to delete some coding from the class but i thinks its not working..

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip: padding;
          background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

i want the box of dropdown have no angle..like this

[image]

i also import some file bootstrap too.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's these two sections:

```
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: 9px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    content: '';
}

.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    content: '';
}
```

Remove them from the bootstrap CSS and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's very bad to modify the core file of any library or framework since your code in the future will be inconsistent which may require you to add a lot of redundant works when the original library has already support it.

For your case, instead of deleting the css styles inside core files of Twitter Bootstrap, you just need to override it:

```
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before {
    content: none;
}

.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
    content: none;
}
```

**[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/114595)**

It's even better by giving your `navbar` a class:

```
<div class="navbar override">
```

This will helps you to target it more precisely instead of override all the `navbar` like above code:

```
.override.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before {
  content: none;
}

.override.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
  content: none;
}
```

**[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/114597)**